# PHP, Jquery, Tablesorter 2.23.1 - how to add or remove a column that has been sorted and refresh the remaining sorting?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I do have a php generated page, with a table that exists after the page loaded.

```
<table id="#previewTable">
    <thead>
        <th class="colA">column a - Firstname</th>
        <th>column b - Lastname</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="colA">Alexander
            </td>
            <td class="colB">Zandvoort
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="colA">Alexander
            </td>
            <td class="colB">Brno
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="colA">Bastian
            </td>
            <td class="colB">Zolder
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

During doc.ready I apply the tablesorter widget like so:

```
var the_table = $('#previewTable');
//the_wrapper ==> any jquery selector (not object!) like '.mywrapper' or '#mywrapper'
//the_table ==> any jquery selector (not object!) like '.mytable' or '#mytable'
//the_childs_class ==> class name of the chilkd rows, like 'child-row' - NO dot!
var idx = $(the_table+'.ts-date').index(); //all headers with german dates
var options = {
    showProcessing: true,
    sortReset   : true,
    saveSortReset : false,
    resort:true,
    widgets: [ 'saveSort','zebra','stickyHeaders' ],
    cssInfoBlock : "row-sorter-false",
    //those rows will NOT be included in a sorting! useful to implement blockwise sorting
    widgetOptions: {
        // number or jquery selector targeting the position:fixed element
        stickyHeaders_offset : 0,
        // added to table ID, if it exists
        stickyHeaders_cloneId : '-sticky',
        // trigger "resize" event on headers
        stickyHeaders_addResizeEvent : true,
        // if false and a caption exist, it won't be included in the sticky header
        stickyHeaders_includeCaption : true,
        // scroll table top into view after filtering
        stickyHeaders_filteredToTop: true,
        /* make the table scroll within its wrapper */
        stickyHeaders_attachTo : the_wrapper
    },
    cssChildRow: the_childs_class,
    dateFormat : "ddmmyyyy", // set the default date format
    idx: { sorter: "shortDate", dateFormat: "ddmmyyyy" }
};

$(the_table).tablesorter(options);
```

After that has been done everything is fine.

Now the users will sort any two of the let's say ten columns A and B in whatever direction.

The saveSort widget remembers everything pretty fine.

We do have a checkbox for each column "hide that column".

Un/checking that checkbox for let's say B should hide/show the according column B, remove the sorting of the rows that has been done through column B and reapply any existing remaining sorting - in this case A.

I tried doing that like so:
    $(document).on('click','.chk_must',function(){ //all checkboxes in MUST

```
    theSortList = $( '#previewTable' ).get(0).config.sortList;
    var new_sort_list = [];

    if($('.chk_must_'+$(this).attr('data-nr')).is(':visible')){
        $('.chk_must_'+$(this).attr('data-nr')).hide();//show or hide M1 and so on rows
        theColumnNumber = $('.chk_must_'+$(this).attr('data-nr')).attr('data-column');

        $(theSortList).each(function(key,element){ //get the header text for each selected
            //var element[0] // var element[1]; //[0]=field number starting at 0, [1]=sort order, whereas 0=ASC and 1=DESC
            if(element[0]!=theColumnNumber){
                new_sort_list.push(element);
            }
        });

        if (new_sort_list.length==0){
            //nothing
        }else{
            $( '#previewTable' ).get(0).config.sortList = [new_sort_list];
            $('#previewTable').trigger( 'sorton',[new_sort_list] );
        }


        $("#previewTable").trigger("updateCache").trigger("updateAll");
        $('#previewTable').trigger('refreshWidgets', true,false);

    }else{
        $('.chk_must_'+$(this).attr('data-nr')).show();//show or hide M1 and so on rows
    }

});
```

What ever I do....the sort is not going to be reseted and redone according to [new_sort_list]but stay the same.

Hiding/Showing of the column itselfs works as well.

It seems like I'm not applying the correct type /format of new_sort_list and that may be the internal cache is not going to be reseted - even not with refreshWidgets and updateCache and all that.

Any ideas what could be done to get this to work?

TIA

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, remove the triggers for `updateCache` & `updateAll`. They aren't needed when only sorting is involved.

The values in `sortList` consist of a column index, and sort direction grouped together. For example:

```
// [ [ columnA, direction ], [ columnB, direction ] ]
table.config.sortList = [ [0,0], [1,0] ];
```

So, the code above has this function:

```
$(theSortList).each(function(key,element){ //get the header text for each selected
    //var element[0] // var element[1]; //[0]=field number starting at 0, [1]=sort order, whereas 0=ASC and 1=DESC
    if(element[0]!=theColumnNumber){
        new_sort_list.push(element);
    }
});
```

This function should be using [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and not the `each` function above which is used for DOM elements.

Maybe instead, if there are only a few columns, you can pick primary columns and sort that one when the others are hidden.

Here is some untested code as an example:

```
var direction = 'asc', // use 'desc' for descending sort
    // sort column priority from left-to-right
    priorities = [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ],

    config = $( '#previewTable' ).get(0).config,
    sortColumn = -1,
    theColumnNumber = $('.chk_must_'+$(this).attr('data-nr')).attr('data-column');

$.each( priorities, function(indx, val) {
    // config.$headerIndexed sets one header cell for each column
    // in a basic array (not a jQuery object set); it is
    // needed for tables with multiple thead rows & colspans
    if ( !config.$headerIndexed[ val ].is(':hidden') ) {
        sortColumn = val;
        break;
    }
});

if ( sortColumn > -1 ) {
    $( '#previewTable' ).trigger('sorton', [ [[ sortColumn, direction ]] ]);
}
```

Or, you could use the [columnSelector widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-column-selector.html) to do the work of hiding & showing columns. And add this very basic code (only written for 2 columns) which updates the sort when the columns change visibility ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/9hLref4s/9/)):

```
$(function () {

    /*** custom css only button popup ***/
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'columnSelector', 'stickyHeaders'],
        widgetOptions: {
            columnSelector_container: $('#columnSelector'),
            columnSelector_mediaquery: false
        }
    }).on('columnUpdate', function(){
        var sortCol = 0,
            s = this.config.selector;
        // if column a is hidden & column b is showing
        // sort column b
        if ( !s.states[0] && s.states[1] ) {
            sortCol = 1;
        }
        $(this).trigger('sorton', [ [[sortCol, 0]] ]);
    });

});
```